# Solve the equation below for the value of $x$

Tags: calculus

Given that $(2^x-4^x)^2+(2^x+4^x)^2=144$ find the value of $x$. I tried solving this but I am stuck with how to deal with the power.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $t=2^x\gt 0$, we have
$$\begin{align}(t-t^2)^2+(t+t^2)^2=144&\Rightarrow 2(t^2+9) (t^2-8)=0\\&\Rightarrow t=2\sqrt 2=2^{3/2}\\&\Rightarrow x=\frac 32.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $2^x=t$. Then you can rewrite the equation given as

$$(t-t^2)^2 + (t+t^2)^2=144$$